# Is this a good practice to use one entity in two different entities in a oneToMany Relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm actually having 3 entities: **Bounty**, **Document**, and **Comment**. When i first made the **Comment** entity, it was to serve the document **Commentary** purpose. Later i have added a newer entity called "**Bounty**", and i was expecting to use the same Comment entity that i was already using in the **Document** entity.

I wish to avoid having one **DocumentComment** entity, and another **BountyComment** entity.

Is having one **Comment** Entity is a good way to procede, or should i rather separate them in two different entities ?

If grouping entites is a good practice, how can i make them fit when there can be duplicate entry ?

Comment: It is a matter of preference. In my opinion, I would prefer to keep the `BountyComment`s separate from the `DocumentComment`s. That will be much cleaner in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both identities have the exact same structure and this fact is never going to change, you could group them together. However, every comment belongs to some other entity, so if it belongs to a Document, it needs a property "document". If it belongs to a Bounty, it needs a property "bounty". So the two are not the same.

If you are using ORM (e.g Doctrine), you can use a shared base class and extend from it. Doctrine will create seperate tables for each type, but you can share functionality between the entity classes. See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html